# Android live build jars: arm64, armabi, mips, mips64, x86

Tags: android, jar, x86, mips

I am using an external library that uses a native lib. In my APK (and inside this external library) separate jars are packaged for:

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

There jars are quite large. I want to remove some of them. Are there any LIVE devices using x86? Is there anything else no longer needed, for example armeabi, when my minSdkVersion = 14?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any LIVE devices using x86?

There are many Android devices powered by x86 CPUs. I would guess that it is 1-2% of the Android device ecosystem, though. Quoting [this article](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/01/07/after-intel-spent-billions-to-subsidize-40m-android-atom-tablets-microsoft-releases-office-only-for-arm):

> Significant Android tablets using Intel Atom processors...include Nokia's N1, Samsung's Galaxy Tab 3 10.1, the Dell Venue 7 and 8, Tesco Hudl 2, the $99 HP 7 tablet, and a variety of products sold under the brands Acer Iconia; Asus MeMo Pad, PadPhone X and Transformer Pad; Lenovo Yoga and Toshiba Excite Go and Encore.

There are far fewer MIPS devices, though, so if you were going to drop one major architecture, I would drop MIPS, unless you have particular distribution plans for your app that require MIPS support.

Comment: just to complement CommonsWare good answer. Most (if not all) of the Asus ZenPhones are x86.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, I will leave them all in. Too bad that my APK is 25 Mb, and more than 12 Mb of it is this one jar of 1.8 Mb (packed) in this many versions...

Answer (score 5):

If performance is not vital you can safely drop all 64 bit libraries without losing support for any devices. All Android 64 bit processors are backwards compatible with 32 bit libraries.

In the Google Play developer console it is also possible to upload a separate APK for each target ABI. This reduces APK size as you no longer have the overhead of including all native libraries. A warning that doing this makes the build, distribution and update process a little more complicated. You can read about the [Multiple APK support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) in the Android documentation and about [how to version your app when building for multiple architectures](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/).

It is possible to get the number of devices that are supported in the Play Store by uploading an APK which only targets a specific architecture. The results for me when uploading an APK targeting Android 4.0+ and a specific ABI were:

```
armeabi-v7a:  7986 devices
x86:          244 devices
```

Here is a table of example devices for each architecture:

[image: ABI Android support]

Comment: Thanks. I removed mips64 since it is backwards compatible with mips anyways.